# Terminating program with error "object 1 beyond bounds"

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, for-loop

Terminating program with the error index 1 beyond bounds. Actually I am trying to parse the columns from csv file. I found few questions on stackoverflow similar to this issue but none of the answer is helpful

```
 NSMutableArray *lines = [sourceFileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"].mutableCopy;
 NSArray *keys = [lines.firstObject componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
 NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
 for (int i = 0; i<keys.count; i++) {
     [result addObject:@{keys[i] : [NSMutableArray array]}];
     }
 [lines removeObjectAtIndex:0];

for (NSString *line in lines) {
// Get a list of all values
NSArray *columns = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

  // Insert the value into the array of the proper key
  NSMutableArray *values = result[1][keys[1]];
  [values addObject:columns[1]];
  NSLog(@"values %@",values);
```

}

Comment: can you paste the error you get from your application here? and which exact line throws exception?

Comment: sorry i didnt get you @ozgur

Comment: "Index 1 beyond bounds" means your array has most likely only one element: index 0 (first element) exists and no error happens; next loop round (index == 1), you attempt to access beyond the bounds of the array and an exception is thrown.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: If you are jumping straight to index 1 (skipping 0), then it could be that the array is outright empty - it doesn't even have one element (but you are using `for` loops, so that's unlikely).

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why the second for loop which iterates the columns array doesn't use `columns.count` -- you have a situation where you have a mismatch between the number of keys in the first line and the number of columns in another line, and your code assumes that never happens

Comment: @stevesliva can u please edit my code and post it as answer?

Comment: @Coolcracker can you paste your array

Comment: that is too long @vishnu

Comment: If we don't know what array contains we can't give exact solution. Better to use pastie.org you can share ur code there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check that your array contains empty indexes, the reason is you are check ing with the help of `[line componentsSeparatedByString:@","]` if any index is empty it surely crash , so in here in before checking remove the empty index from array using following concept

```
for (int j=[lines count]-1; j>=0; j--)
    if ([[lines objectAtIndex:j] length] == 0)
        [lines removeObjectAtIndex:j];
```